# How found sha256 of package python for import in my project?

Tags: python, docker, hash, pypi

I'm trying to import a new package python (PyGreSQL) with a requirements file in new docker container.
All others package in this file has this format :

`PyMySQL==0.7.11 --hash=sha256:ac3dfb1f650582eca2e1e0701598bc04364ac464daa425cbbc26bb32ae54cdd5`

I have found my package, found hash the md5 value, sha1 value but no trace of sha256 hash.
How I can found this hash sha256 ? in package pypi page for conclude my import ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this :

```
wget urltothesourcepackage
sha256sum sourcepackage.tar.gz
```

Copy/paste the checksum and reuse in requirement file.